# asp.net panel scroll bar not visible in iphone browser

Tags: asp.net, ipad, scrollbar, panel

I making web application for iphone user. I have HTML table structure inside asp.net panel and i have set panel's scrollbar property to vertical. It works fine in all the browsers but not working in iphone browser. 
Any ideas how can i set scroll bar visibility.

Thanks,
Mehul Makwana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It will save you hours of time messing about with cross browser issues, even though it's only in Alpha at the moment.

Comment: is there anything component for scroll because i didnt found.

Comment: Putting content into panels or divs with their own scroll bar is not a good idea on a mobile. The screen is small enough as it is. Let the iPhone scrollbar do its own thing.